# Behaviour of JQuery UI datepicker on asynchronous call, multiple issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm calling a [Bootstrap asynchronous-modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) that displays a form with a the [JQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

This is my JS code and I'll place the refering numbers as comments inside the code for my multiple questions.

```
$('body').on('click', '#datepicker', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.warn($(this));

        var array = ["2017-01-14","2017-01-16","2017-01-22"];
        $('#datepicker').focus().datepicker({ // Question #1
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', date);
                return [ array.indexOf(string) === -1 ]
                console.warn(date, string, array);
            }, // Question #3
            firstDay: 1,
            format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            orientation: 'bottom left',
            zIndexOffset: '99',
            nextText: 'M',
            startView: 0,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minViewMode: 0,
            maxViewMode: 1,
            language: '<?php if ($_SESSION['lang']) echo $_SESSION['lang']; else echo 'en'; ?>'
        }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            $('.datepicker').hide();
            $(this).blur();
        })
        .datepicker('setStartDate', new Date()); // Question #2

    });
```

1) The first issue is that I have to click on the datepicker input at least two times to open it at all. Without `focus()` it wouldn't show or open at all. Still I don't know how to open it with the first click.

2) I tried to put every option inside the big block the first time I use `.datepicker({...` but when I add `setStartDate: new Date(),` (in the mentioned block inside up there) this function doesn't work. (It disables previous dates from being selectable). It only works this way like you see it in the code now. Why is that?

3) The `beforeShowDay` option seems to be ignored at all, because I don't even get the `console.warn` output. Even If I put that outside like the function of Question #2. Has this something to do with the datepicker being called asynchronously? How can I fix that this would work?

Note: I would really appreciate your answer to my questions, even if you help me with only one of them.

Note2: I'm using `$('body').on('click', '#datepicker', function (e) {` because it seems to be the only solution to make javascript detect asynchronous loaded content.

Comment: First thing: You absolutely *don't* want to initialize the datepicker inside a "click" event handler. Initialize the datepicker on page load. You can show or hide it on click, but do not re-initialize it. Also, datepickers have an [icon trigger option](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) that probably already does that. Second thing: You don't want to write PHP variables into your JS. Move all your JS to static .js files, use HTML `data-*` attributes if you want to transfer dynamic values from your markup to your scripts.

Comment: There is no option named `setStartDate` mentioned in the [API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (there is also no method of that name). No surprise that this does not work.

Comment: Your code does not match the jquery UI datepicker API, as @VincenzoC pointed out, they match a mix of JQueryUI's datepicker and bootstrap datepicker. Make sure you use only one of these, and clarify the code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need `focus()`, if you remove it the picker will open the first time you'll focus into it. Since your content is loaded asynchronously you can use [bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) like `shown.bs.modal`. This event is fired when the modal is shown.
2. From your question **is not clear** if you are using [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (see below). [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) is the option to use to disable previous dates with bootstrap datepicker, while [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) is used for jQuery UI component
3. `console.warn` should be placed **before** return statement.

#### What datepicker are you using?

<del>From the option you used in your `datepicker` function, it seems that you are **NOT** using [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), but you are using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)</del>. In thh code of your question you are mixing options of the two components, for example:

- `firstDay`, `nextText`, `changeMonth`, `changeYear` are valid only for jQuery UI datepicker
- `format`, `orientation`, `zIndexOffset`, `startView`, `minViewMode`, `maxViewMode`, `language` are valid only for bootstrap datepicker
- `beforeShowDay` is valid for both components.

Note that:

- date format (jQuery UI: [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat), bootstrap: [`format`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format))
- change events (jQuery UI: [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect), bootstrap: [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate))
- localization (jQuery UI: see *Localization* section in the docs, bootstrap: [`language`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#language))

**differ** between components.

Here an example using both jQuery UI and bootstrap datepicker. Note that you have to use [no conflict mode](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#no-conflict-mode), if you import both, because both libaries has the `datepicker` method:

```js
var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var array = ["2017-01-14","2017-01-16","2017-01-22"];
  $('#datepicker1').bootstrapDP({ // Question #1
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      // Use moment istead of jQuery.datepicker.formatDate
      var string = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      //console.warn(date, string, array);
      return [ array.indexOf(string) === -1 ]
    },
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    orientation: 'bottom left',
    zIndexOffset: '99',
    startView: 0,
    minViewMode: 0,
    maxViewMode: 1,
    language: 'en',
    startDate: new Date()
  }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $('.datepicker').hide();
    $(this).blur();
  })
  
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', date);
      //console.warn(date, string, array);
      return [ array.indexOf(string) === -1 ]
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    nextText: 'M',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(){
      $(this).blur();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class='modal fade'>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="datepicker">Date bootstrap</label>
          <input type="text" id="datepicker1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="datepicker">Date jQuery UI</label>
          <input type="text" id="datepicker2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my bootstrap example, I've used [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) instead `jQuery.datepicker.formatDate`, to show how you can to the same thing without  jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

1. You call `.focus()` *before* the datepicker has been built. Call `.focus()` *after*.
2. (+1 for @VincenzoC to have taken the time to point at another datepicker library) : the docs say `setStartDate` is a *method* (which can be called after the datepicker has been created). The initial option is : `startDate` (read [the documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate))
3. That's beacuase you are mixing two libraries, and obviously, in your case, the bootstrap version is the one which stays active. Choose one of the two libraries, and stick to its API.

Answer (score -1):

> 1) The first issue is that I have to click on the datepicker input at
>   least two times to open it at all. Without focus() it wouldn't show or
>   open at all. Still I don't know how to open it with the first click.

It's because you are trying to initialize the datepicker when clicking the `input`. So the first time you click the input it initialize the datepicker to that input and then when you click the second time then that's when the calendar shows up.

You can use this to initialize datepicker in the input at page load:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
```

> 2) I tried to put every option inside the big block the first time I
>   use .datepicker({... but when I add setStartDate: new Date(), (in the
>   mentioned block inside up there) this function doesn't work. (It
>   disables previous dates from being selectable). It only works this way
>   like you see it in the code now. Why is that?

It's because there's no `setStartDate` method, instead use `setDate`.

e.g.

```
}).datepicker('setDate', '01/01/2017')
```

[Source](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

> 3) The beforeShowDay option seems to be ignored at all, because I
>   don't even get the console.warn output. Even If I put that outside
>   like the function of Question #2. Has this something to do with the
>   datepicker being called asynchronously? How can I fix that this would
>   work?

It is working, but the reason why `console.warn` output not running it's because you've put it after your return.

This one:

```
return [array.indexOf(string) === -1];
console.warn(date, string, array);
```

Should be the other way around so it runs the `console.warn` before the return.

```
console.warn(date, string, array);
return [array.indexOf(string) === -1];
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zscrebur/)

Comment: 1.) except... the input doesn't exist at page load. Additionally, the .focus is meant to cause it to popup after initialization, but the op called .focus too early. it should happen *after* the datepicker is initialized. Lastly, there really needs to be logic put in place to prevent re-initialization.